# X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Tags: 16.04, x11-forwarding

I was running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with a msi B150M PRO-VDH. When I try to run remotly a graphic program (xcrysden), I don't get the display in my local machine, and instead I get the following error:

```
Package ImageMagick's convert: /usr/bin/convert
Package ImageMagick's import: /usr/bin/import
Package Ppmtompeg: /usr/bin/ppmtompeg
Package Xwd: /usr/bin/xwd
Executing: /usr/local/lib/xcrysden-1.5.53/ftnunit
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  809
Current serial number in output stream:  810
```

I have forwarded the X11, and for instance xclock shows without any problem.
Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, it's been ages since this question was asked, but by any chance do you remember the solution? I'm having the same issue with xcrysden on remote rhel 7. The solutions suggested on xcrysden forum doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular error means you can't create an OpenGL context across the network.  OpenGL is the library used to connect to the local graphics processing unit  (GPU) for 3-D graphics hardware acceleration.  There is not networked support for OpenGL, so trying to create a context over the network fails.

Comment: Hi again @Stephen M. Webb,
Thank you for your answer, but I do not understand how to fix the problem. 
Actually, the problem I reported was when the remote machine is red hat. However i can get the display without any problem from another ubuntu machine.
Best regards and thank you.

Comment: @AlejandraGDR, Do both machine have same graphic adapter type and driver? Check with `sudo lshw -c display`